# update database value on laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-controller

does laravel have short cut for $i++; i want to update my database value went seomething happend. on php i could just use sql like

```
UPDATE goods SET qty++ WHERE id = '4'
```

here is my `controller` code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      $g = new goods();
      $g->qty = ++;
      $g->save();
}
```

Comment: what is Your Expected output and what are you trying to do

Comment: If i have stuff let say A with QTY of 10 when i do something i would be update the QTY based on what the QTY i inputed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
$post      = Goods::find(3);
$post->qty = $post->qty + 1;
$post->save();
```

you can just find that record and update with +1.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#increment-and-decrement
For example: `DB::table('users')->increment('votes', 5);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $g = goods::find(4);
    $g->qty += 1;
    $g->save;
}
```

Comment: No I can’t... laravel think I’m going to insert new data... not update it

Comment: @MartinChristopher you are use `new` keyword, so laravel think you are insert new data. please remove new keyword and use this code `$g = goods::find(4);`

Comment: Please accept and upvoted my answer to helpful other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just call `++` on nothing, and doing (if it would work) would just add 1.
Why not just say `$g->qty = 1;`?
If you already have some value in `qty`, then call `$g->qty++;` and then call `->save();` on it (note the "()").